# nested_form reorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form with dynamic fields (has_many associated model) which can be added/removed with the help of nested_form gem (Thank you, Ryan Bates!).

Now, I'd like to give user a possibility to reorder these fields.

Let's say nested models have "order_nr" integer field that can be used for ordering them.
So, basically, swapping these numbers of the neighbour elements will change their order.

I could write some javascript to swap the form elements and their hidden fields with these numbers, populate order numbers for newly created elements with some kind of ajax requests, but I have a strong feeling there should be already some kind of common solution for this task.

So, the question is: what's a good/common/ready/reasonable approach to solving this task?